# Can't UNION on primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, inner-join, union

So these are 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM CourseGrade; 
SELECT * FROM LetterGrades;
```

[image]

When I do this UNION to see which LetterGradeId has which LetterGrade:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM CourseGrade
    INNER JOIN LetterGrades
    ON CourseGrade.LetterGradeId=LetterGrades.LetterGradeId;
```

I'm getting an error saying

```
Invalid column name 'LetterGradeId'.
```

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Error message says what it means.

Comment: There is nothing with "UNION", although it's in the tags and title.

Answer (score 2):

you misspelled the name  cg.LetterGradedId

```
SELECT * 
FROM CourseGrade cg
INNER JOIN LetterGrades lg
ON cg.LetterGradedId=lg.LetterGradeId;
```

Comment: thanks...didn't realize.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CourseGrade cg
INNER JOIN LetterGrades lg
ON cg.LetterGradedId=lg.LetterGradeId;
```

Comment: didn't work. same error.

Comment: in the CourseGrade table it is LaterGradedId (one extra letter), you still need to do the aliases

Comment: thanks....damn what a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

your query is correct but you missed spelled the column name in the first table.

this should work:

```
     
SELECT * 
    FROM CourseGrade
    INNER JOIN LetterGrades
    ON CourseGrade.LetterGradedId=LetterGrades.LetterGradeId;
```

note that you named the colum as "LetterGrade**d**Id" not as LetterGradeId :)

Comment: why did I get negative voting? when I was analyzing the problem there was only one post, which is Zdravko Danev's. By the time I posted my solution he released what the problem was and other person pointed to it. I should have not been down voted for that delay :(